# Always Getting "Input" "0x0" from web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)

Tags: web3js

I send a transaction i.e

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            to: toAddress,
            from: fromAddress,
            value: web3.toWei(amount, 'ether'),
            data : inputData,
        });
```

But when I am trying to get transaction data from local RPC(Ganache) i.e

```
web3.eth.getTransaction(tsHash,function(error,data){
            if (error) {

            }else {
               console.log(data); 
            }
        });
```

Return all fields perfectly except "input".i.e

```
{"hash":"0x6xxxxxcb877","nonce":3,"blockHash":"0x0bxxxxxxx5798","blockNumber":4,"transactionIndex":0,"from":"0x4xxxxxxxx0abb","to":"0x5xxxxxxxxe649","value":"20000000000000000","gas":2000002,"gasPrice":"1000000000","input":"0x0"}
```

Comment: Are you sure `inputDaTa` is not empty? Is it formatted as hexadecimal?

Comment: Hi @ Ismael, thanks for time. Yes i passed a string to "data" field of "sendTransaction()" method of web3.js.